# How do I fix this pthread_create type error?

Tags: c

I'm attempting to use threading in my coursework, but keep running into an error that has me stuck.

I'm trying to use this:

```
 pthread_create(&pro, NULL, producer, (void *) &temp);
 pthread_create(&con, NULL, consumer, (void *) &temp);
```

to call these functions:

```
 void producer (void *t)
 void consumer (void *t)
```

I've worked this code from examples given to me by a tutor, but I don't know if the example given to me works.

The warning I get is:

```
task2.c:37:5: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from
incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

pthread_create(&con, NULL, consumer, (void *) &temp);
                           ^ In file included from task2.c:3:0: 
  /usr/include/pthread.h:244:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but
    argument is of type ‘void (*)(void*)’
```

I am using `gcc -pthread` when compiling and I am getting a similar warning for the `producer()` function as well. This is my first attempt at threading, so the usage of `pthread_create()` is new to me.

Can anyone help clarify this issue?

Comment: According to man page `start_routine` should return `void*`.

Answer (score 4):

Your function does not match the expected type which is `void * (*)(void *)` as said in the error you get.

Try changing your functions to return `void *`

Answer (score 1):

I should have declared my functions as;

```
void *producer (void *t);
```

and my fourth argument did not need the (void *).